# Unknown type for lambda consumer parameter when using generic class

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

I have a similar code to the one below, and for some reason when I call a method that takes a `Consumer<BigDecimal>` parameter with a lambda, the lambda parameter is of type `Object` instead of `BigDecimal`. That results in "Cannot resolve method" inside lambda if any method of `BigDecimal` lambda param is called. This happens only when the method taking the consumer is in a generic class, however non of the generics are participating in that consumer-taking method.

```
public class Creator<T> {

    private T something;

    private Consumer<BigDecimal> consumer;

    public Creator(T something) {
        this.something = something;
    }

    public void create(Consumer<BigDecimal> consumer) {
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

}

public class Processor {
    public void process(Creator creator) {
        creator.create(big -> big.abs());
                                  ^^^^^-------------------- Cannot resolve method
    }
}
```

If I remove generic param `<T>` from Creator class, it works, even though the generics do not touch the `create()` method

What's wrong with this?

Comment: NO...but why are you using RAW types??

Comment: And ... why are you ignoring the raw type warnings?  They are there to tell you that you're about to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: Raw type warnings? I didnt get any in intellij .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public void process(Creator creator) {
```

In this line, you use `Creator` as a raw type, which basically destroys type inference.

Write, at the very least,

```
public void process(Creator<?> creator) {
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I actually never used `<?>` much. Anyway, could you elaborate why this is needed despite the create() method does not participate in the class' generics at all.

Comment: @redhead: raw types exist for compatibility with pre-Generics code and will invariably turn off generic operations *completely*. So even if the generic parameter type of `create` is unrelated to the class’ parameter, calling this method on a raw type, turning off Generic operations, will behave like invoking a method with a `create(Consumer)` signature like in pre-Generics times.

Answer (score 5):

As Louis Wasserman have already told you are removing the type inference by writing

```
public void process(Creator creator) {
```

Apart from the solution Louis have given you can also write it like

```
public <T> void process(Creator<T> creator) {
```

By going this way you can utilise T in your method process() for other purposes

Answer (score 1):

Using `public <T> void process(Creator<T> creator)` will solve your purpose and give you flexibility to provide various types of checks inside the process method like

```
T field = creator.getSomeFieldofCreator()
```

However type of this example field `someFieldofCreator` should be `T` inside the `Creator` class

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `process()` to `public void process(Creator<?> creator) {`.
This should solve the issue.